# Why does this filter function set the indexes equal to one another?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

```
const nonDuplicate = function(arr) {
    let filteredArr = arr.filter(function(item, index){
        if(arr.indexOf(item) === index)
            return item
    })
    console.log(filteredArr)
}
nonDuplicate([1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6])
```

Can someone walk me through why this works in terms of removing duplicates in an array? What is the point of setting the indexes equal to one another?

Comment: nothing is getting set equal to each other. `===` is an equality test. As for why it works: imagine you have a list [1,1,1,1,1], what is the index of "1" in that list? Remember, you can only get one answer, so for how many of the elements in that list will that be the case?

Comment: Learn to debug `console.log(arr.indexOf(item), index, arr.indexOf(item) === index)`

Answer (score 0):

> What is the point of setting the indexes equal to one another?

I assume you're referring to this line:

```
        if(arr.indexOf(item) === index)
```

The `===` operator is actually a [*strict equality*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity) operator.  It actually resolves to a boolean... `true` or `false`.

Open up a JavaScript console and enter the following:

```
1 === 1
```

You'll get back `true`.  Likewise, if you enter `1 === 2`, you'll get `false`.

Now, to the actual code, there is the [`indexOf` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).  This returns back the index of the item in the array, or `-1` if it's not found.  So, for each item in the array, they check to see if the *first index* of this particular item is equal to the *index* of this particular item.  The idea being that by the time the loop gets to the second `1` in that example array, `indexOf` is actually going to return `0` because the first index that matches the value `1` is `0`.